# Laravel Message Bag Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Am working on form validations for newsletter for a project am on, the news letter form appears on every page so it will also appear on the longin and registration page so i decided to make use of Laravel Message Bags to store the news letter errors but it keeps giving me an undefined property error on the actual page i check and output echo the errors, i don't know if am doing something wrong here are the details though!

The Error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::$newsletter
```

My code In the Controller:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($inputs, "newsletter");
```

My code in the View:

```
 @if($errors->newsletter->any())

 <p>
    {{$errors->newsletter->any()}}
 </p>
```

Answer (score 10):

**Code in controller:**

```
         $post_data = Input::all();

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ));


    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return Redirect::back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors(['auth-validation' => 'ERROR: in validation!']);
    }
```

**Code in vew:**

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach($errors->getMessages() as $this_error)
        <p style="color: red;">{{$this_error[0]}}</p>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: You can simply use `$errors->all('<p style="color: red;">:message</p>')`. The view will verify and write only on error

Answer (score 8):

The `RedirectResponse` class function `withErrors()` doesn't have a second parameter..

The function `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse.php -> withErrors()`:

```
/**
 * Flash a container of errors to the session.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Contracts\MessageProviderInterface|array  $provider
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function withErrors($provider)
{
    if ($provider instanceof MessageProviderInterface)
    {
        $this->with('errors', $provider->getMessageBag());
    }
    else
    {
        $this->with('errors', new MessageBag((array) $provider));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So, if you really want to use the `MessageBag` then this should work (didn't test it):

```
$your_message_bag = new Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
$your_message_bag->add('foo', 'bar');

return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($your_message_bag->all());
```

Comment: what should i put in place "foo" and the "bar"

Comment: That's just a example how to add an item to the `MessageBag` to make the example more complete. I understand from your question that you already are storing messages inside a MessageBag `i decided to make use of Laravel Message Bags to store the news letter errors`, so if you already have the messages then you only have to replace the variable `$your_message_bag` to your message bag variable in the `withErrors()` function.

Comment: return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator, 'login'); According to Laravel documentation [link]http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation

Comment: In Laravel 5 (not tested in L4) you can use `return back()->withInput()->withErrors([$custom1, $customN]);`. I deduced from your response so I thought this could help somebody.

Comment: whats foo bar? an example of what? error message? or error key?

Answer (score 1):

`withErrors` should receive the messages from validator object. After your validation process something like:

```
  $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $validation_rules);
  if (!$validation->passes()){
       return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation->messages());
  }
```

I hope it works fine for you.

Comment: Hi @fmgonzalez i'm actually trying to create a message bag but in the view where i try to check for errors it keeps giving error saying saying `Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::$newsletter`

Answer (score -1):

You can write a function like this

```
if(!function_exists('errors_for')) {

 function errors_for($attribute = null, $errors = null) {

    if($errors && $errors->any()) {

        return '<p class="text-danger">'.$errors->first($attribute).'</p>';

    }   

 }

}
```

then in your View

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="bio">Bio</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" name="bio"></textarea>
</div>
{!! errors_for('bio',$errors) !!}
```

learnt from Jeffrey Way on Laracasts